# php variable why it is visible in other files without being declared global?

Tags: php, global

I defined the following files

**0.php**

```
<?php
$v='good';
echo 'In file: '.__FILE__." v={$v}<br>\n";
?>
```

**1.php**

```
<?php 
require '0.php';
echo 'In file: '.__FILE__." v={$v}<br>\n";
?>
```

**2.php**

```
<?php 
require '1.php';
echo 'In file: '.__FILE__." v={$v}<br>\n";
?>
```

When I run the 2.php the output is:

```
In file: /xxx/httpdocs/0.php v=good

In file: /xxx/httpdocs/1.php v=good

In file: /xxx/httpdocs/2.php v=good
```

Why is that ? shouldn't 'v' be visible to other files only if defined as global ? (this is what is told !).

Comment: Including/requiring files is not a scope boundary.  When including/requiring a file, it's *very nearly identical to* (and for most intents and purposes can be thought of as) pasting the code of that file in that spot.

Comment: So what is the meaning of global if not inside a function , global is meant only inside functions ?

Comment: To my knowledge, yes.  There may be other implications in terms of classes and OOP, with which I'm otherwise unfamiliar.

Comment: The manual details this behavior, https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php. `The scope of a variable is the context within which it is defined. For the most part all PHP variables only have a single scope. This single scope spans included and required files as well.` and `Here the $a variable will be available within the included b.inc script. However, within user-defined functions a local function scope is introduced. Any variable used inside a function is by default limited to the local function scope. `

Comment: The `global` keyword allows you to use a global variable inside a function where it wouldn't otherwise be visible. It doesn't declare a variable as global. A variable is automatically global if it's declared outside of any function or class